# Can't set a HTML date field value with Selenium on mobiles

Tags: java, html, selenium, date, mobile

I need to set the value of a date field on an HTML page using Selenium. The date field on the page looks like this:

```
<input aria-invalid="false" id="datepicker-date-input" type="date" min="2000-01-01" max="2100-12-31" pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}" value>
```

When I run my Selenium script using ChromeDriver on a PC:

```
WebElement myDate = getDriver().findElement(By.id("datepicker-date-input"));
myDate.sendKeys("2022-01-28");
```

It works well since on Chrome, I can simply type the date in the field. However, when I run it using a mobile WebDriver (whether Android or iOS), it fails as those mobile drivers won't let me enter text in a  field.

I have tried using Javascript like this:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)getDriver();
String script = "document.getElementById('datepicker-date-input').value = '2022-01-28'";
js.executeScript(script);
```

With this I can see the value being correctly entered in the field. However, as soon as I click on the component, the value disappears. It also goes blank if I just click on the "submit" button.

Any suggestions on either a different way of setting the date or for not losing the value?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a jquery datepicker you probably want:

```
jQuery('#datepicker-date-input').val('2022-01-28')
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. It's not a jQuery datepicker per se, just an HTML5 input type=date. jQuery seems worth exploring as it can technically be injected on the page through the Selenium test - might be a solution. I'll research this.